# Why the selected item in a drop-down menu cannot be found in the HTML source code

Tags: html, css

For the highlighted part in the following screenshot

[image: Chrome Inspect]

I only see the following code for the Drop-Down menu part when using Google Chrome Inspect function...

```
<div id="x-auto-325" class=" x-component" style="width: 250px;">
    <div class=" x-form-field-wrap  x-component  x-trigger-wrap-focus" id="x-auto-326" role="combobox" style="width: 250px; height: 22px;">
        <input type="text" class=" x-form-field x-form-text x-triggerfield-noedit  x-form-focus" id="x-auto-326-input" tabindex="0" readonly="" autocomplete="off" aria-owns="x-auto-327" style="width: 233px; height: 22px;">
        <img class="x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-arrow " src="http://prodv2crudp01:50080/com.kapowtech.scheduler.GUI/clear.gif" id="x-auto-328">
    </div>
</div>
```

I searched the whole page and cannot find word "Default project"... How is it possible?

[image: Search Result]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way or us to answer this unless we can see the actual page itself

Comment: @j08691 sorry it's inside our company's internal network....

Answer (score 0):

Try using the search box on Inspect element `CTRL + F` and search the word: `Default project`.

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I did... Find nothing...